# Azure DevOps IIS deployment without WinRM

Tags: azure-devops

What options are there to deploy a web application to a heavily locked down machine without `WinRM`?

The situation is as followed.

1. Code is in Azure DevOps cloud
2. Release server is in a semi-secured area with access to download artifacts from DevOps
3. Target server is in a very locked down zone.

If release server can only copy files to a specific temporary folder target machine, is there a way to do deployment to it without WinRM?

My initial thought is to have a script on the Target machine to watch for the artifact showing up and deploy it. I want to know if there's a better way or if that's my best option?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Just checking in to see if you need any further help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If release server can only copy files to a specific temporary folder
>   target machine, is there a way to do deployment to it without WinRM?

If you've read document [Deploy your Web Deploy package to IIS servers using WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm?view=azure-devops), you would find the notice below the title:

*A simpler way to deploy web applications to IIS servers is by using deployment groups instead of WinRM.*

So you can consider using [Deployment Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops#create-a-deployment-group) as a simpler direction. And here're some discussions([#1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/3046#issuecomment-455149734), [#2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/3370#issuecomment-464030669)) which may help you to do a choice between WinRM and Deployment Group depending on your needs.

**Update1:**

> My initial thought is to have a script on the Target machine to watch
>   for the artifact showing up and deploy it. I want to know if there's a
>   better way or if that's my best option?

In your specific scenario, it's one choice when the target server cannot have line of sights to the Azure DevOp/TFS server and you can't(or maybe not want to) use WinRM.

Comment: What if the destination server cannot have line of sights to the Azure DevOp/TFS server? Only the Release server can see it.

Comment: @ShuberFu If only the release server has the access to tfs/azure devops service, Deployment group can't be used to deploy the app to target server's IIS server, instead it can only be used to deploy app to release server's IIS server... In this situation, I agree with your initial thought, you can use the script running in your release server to make the following job.(Copy the artifact and deploy it via release pipeline)

Comment: Since your target server is very locked down, Azure Devops can't deploy anything directly to it, instead the release server is supported. Under this circumstances, WInRM and deployment group aren't suitable for you. Your initial though could be a choice :-)

Comment: I'm referring to something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler

Comment: The IIS 7 Web Deploy seems not to be an azure devops task. I checked the document but I didn't find any clue that the action of deploy can be done by command-line. I think  the CD process for this can't work until the deployment to Locked server from release server can be done via local command-line.